# Add/Remove code of compiled java code

Tags: java, parsing, pdf, organization

I wanna know if It's possible to add/remove code to a .jar file.

Here's my case:

I have a program to organize some pdf files by company, type and date in a determined directory. But when I parse some of the pdf file the company name may be incorrect, mostly because of the way the pdf was generated.

the company name in the file pdf is:
 `COMPANY & MAN'S`

but when converted it might outputs:
 `CO MPA NY & MAN S`

Knowing this I have blocks to every file type to handle this kind of exception.

is this way:

```
static String DSN(String EDIT_DSN)
{
    EDIT_DSN = EDIT_DSN.replaceAll("CO MPA NY & MAN S", "COMPANY & MAN'S");
    return EDIT_DSN;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is create another piece of code that is able to add/edit/remove lines to this blocks. Is it possible? if it is, how should I do it?

Comment: Your question is unclear: Title indicates you want to add bytecode at runtime, in your post however you talk about pdfs and scanning them.

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple: you don't hard code these strings in your code.

Instead, you put the strings into a text file (for example a Java property file).

Then your "mapper" code simply reads the mappings from such text files. So you don't have to change your Java classes, just feed different text files to it.